# Code to get the IP address and format it to run in nmap

Tags: bash, ip-address, awk

For scanning my subnet using my IP address, I need to run the following command

```
nmap -sn 192.168.100.*
```

I want to extend this functionality such that I don't have to manually specify the first three parts of the IP range myself. I came up with this rough solution.

```
ip=$( hostname -I | awk '{print $1}' | awk -F. '{print $1; print $2; print $3}' ORS="."; echo -n "*"); 
nmap -sn $ip
```

Is there a more cleaner way of achieving the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is pretty reasonable.  I'd have `awk` do a bit more of the work:

```
ip=$( hostname -I | awk '{print $1}' | awk -F. '{OFS="."; print $1, $2, $3,"*"}'; );
```

I switched from `ORS` (output record separator) to `OFS` (output field separator) to use `print` in `awk` with commas.  The commas tell it that we have multiple fields which gets rid of two "extra" `print` statements.  This also let me move the literal `*` inside of `awk` which eliminates the shell `echo`.  So I feel this is more succinct without being harder to follow.

It might be nice to combine the `awk`s into one, but it is pretty clear what each one does and it isn't like you're processing reams of data here.

Comment: You could drop `awk '{print $1}'` in the middle and expect the same output ;-)

Answer (score 6):

You can do it purely in Bash, using [`${parameter%word}`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to strip off the last octet from the IP address.

```
hostname -I | while read ip _ ; do
    nmap -sn  ${ip%.*}.\*
done
```

Note that `hostname -I` is not portable: the `-I` option appears to be a GNU extension.

Comment: Although it's reasonable to expect that `hostname -I` will not output something malicious, as a rule of thumb it's always good to double-quote variables used in command arguments, and written like this might be slightly kinder on the eyes too: `nmap -sn "${ip%.*}.*"`